# display: block css is not working in div element?

Tags: html, css, display

here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/r62p4209/

I build search bar with some company brand name and few button on right, and search bar is in the middle.

I want that as we reduce to 786px width (of screen) then search bar (from "search by:" up to button "Go!" ) to move on to next line.
but my code not working as expected. what is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test5</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test5.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="center">
 <div class="qwert" id="abc1">
    <a id="Home" href="www.bookavanue.com"><b>Brand</b></a>
 </div>
 <div class="qwert" id="abc3">
    <button id="Register" type="button">Register</button>
    <button id="Login" type="button">Log In</button>
    <button id="Cart" type="button">Cart</button>
 </div>
 <div class="qwert" id="abc2">
    <div id="abcd1">
        <label for="Search">Search by:</label>
            <select value="Title">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>
            </select>
            <select value="All Books">
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>
            </select> 
    </div>
    <div id="abcd2">
        <input id="Search" type="text" name="Search your book" 
        placeholder="Search Your Books...">
    </div>
    <div id="abcd3">
        <button id="Go" type="Search">Go!</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#abc1{
 float: left;
 width: 110px;
}
#abc3{
 float: right;
 width: 185px;
 text-align: right;
}
#abc2{
 display: block;
 width: auto;
}
#abcd1{
 float: left;
 width: 220px;
}
#abcd3{
 float: right;
 width: 40px;
 text-align: right;
}
#abcd2{
 width: calc(100% - 270px);
 display: inline-block;
}
input{
 width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 786px){
 #abc2{
    width: calc(100% - 295px);
    display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

Comment: 768 >< expanding or reducing?

Comment: @SleekGeek for reducing.

Comment: Then change min-width: 786px to max-width: 768px before anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add [clear:both](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) property ... on your abc2 element [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/r62p4209/2/)

```
  #abc2.qwert{
    clear:both;
  }
```

Comment: Even without that, it appears to be working when you reduce to far less than 786px, but if you reduce right about 786px than it is not working the "search by" with two drop down not moving to next line at that time.!

Comment: Hi sure, the clear:both property prevents floating elements on the left or the right side of a specified element,  that is why your element will move a to a new line if it reach some left or right floating element....